# Sender Synth example can't build - symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: audiokit, sender, synth, audiobus

I have follow the [Sender synth](https://audiokit.io/audiobus/sender-synth/) example, with XCode 10.1, Audiokit 4.5.5. But when I try to build it (part Audiobus and Integration), it fails with this error:

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABPort", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudiobusController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudioSenderPort", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudioFilterPort", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o
  "_ABConnectionsChangedNotification", referenced from:
      SenderSynth.Audiobus.(startObservingAudiobusConnections in _37936C4CF5A242669D2CAF61EB84EA24)() -> () in Audiobus.o
      SenderSynth.Audiobus.(stopObservingAudiobusConnections in _37936C4CF5A242669D2CAF61EB84EA24)() -> () in Audiobus.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to build with my iphone SE connected via usb and with Audiobus app installed on it.
I tried also targeting simulator, but same error occurs with x86_64 rather than arm64.
I searched and try many things but did not find any solution. I read many times the tutorial but I don't see anything I forgot. 
What is missing. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

These are symbols from the AudioBus SDK; you need to link with the SDK and using your API key to resolve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue, try adding "$(inherited)" to your targets build settings under "other linker flags".

https://heroes.audiob.us/discussion/706/sendersynth-tutorial-audiobus-error/p1